# Getting data as key value pairs having columns and its calculated values on ag-gird

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I've used ag-grid with some columns using direct values and some columns using valueGetters.

```
  columnDef: ColDef[] = [
    { field: 'column1' },
    { field: 'column2' },
    { headerName: 'column3', valueGetter: this.getColumn3Value }
  ];
```

The actual row data will be available to me, since I've provided the ag-grid with row data. The problem is that I could not find any way to get the data in the below format:

**Key value pair having columns as key and rendered value obtained from valueGetters of ag-grid as value.**

eg:
[{column1:'column1Data', column2: 'column2Data', column3: 'column3Data_found_using_valueGetter'}]

Otherwise I have to process the actual row data to get the above format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've got a solution for this problem.

In my research, there is no particular method to retrieve the details displayed on ag-grid.
But we can use getDataAsCsv() method, which will return the headers and row values of ag-grid in csv format, we can format the data into desired format.

CSV data:

```
"Athlete","Country","Sport","Total"
"Eamon Sullivan","Australia","Swimming","3"
"Dara Torres","United States","Swimming","3"
```

Here is the code to get key value pairs of data displayed on ag-grid:

```
onGridReady(event){
   this.gridApi = event.api;
}

csvToKeyvaluePair() {
    // Removes the doube quotes present on each string
    let csvData = this.gridApi.getDataAsCsv().replace(/"/g, "");

    // Splits header and each row values
    let [header, ...values] = csvData.split('\n');

    // Returns an array of header value 
    let headerLine = header.split(',');

    // Generate an array of key value pairs
    let displayedData = values.map((item, index) => {
      return item.split(',').reduce((result, current, index) => ({ ...index === 1 ? { [headerLine[0]]: result } : result, ...index === 1 ? { [headerLine[1]]: current } : { [headerLine[index]]: current } }));
    });

    //  Displays row data in key value pairs
    console.log(displayedData);
}
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    Athlete: "Eamon Sullivan",
    Country: "Australia",
    Sport: "Swimming",
    Total: "3"
  },
  {
    Athlete: "Dara Torres",
    Country: "United States",
    Sport: "Swimming",
    Total: "3"
  }
]
```